# Why do the energy eigenvalues never depend on the position coordinate $x$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, schroedinger-equation, commutator, eigenvalue

The eigenvalues of the Hamiltonian can depend on momentum $p$, only for a free particle where $[\hat p,\hat H]=0$. In this case, since the energy and momentum eigenvalues are given by the relations $$E=\frac{\hbar^2k^2}{2m},~ p=\hbar k$$ respectively, they jointly make the energy $E$ depend on momentum as $$E=\frac{p^2}{2m},$$ reproducing the classical result. But the energy eigenvalues never depend on the position coordinate $x$. I cannot remember any example where the energy eigenvalue varied as a function of $x$. However, I have a feeling that this is related to the noncommutativity of $\hat x$ and $\hat H$ i.e. $[\hat x,\hat H]\neq 0$. But I do not have a proof of this.

Comment: Consider what happens to the position state of a particle in a pure momentum eigenstate.

Comment: I am not interested in the eigenvalue of any operator but that of the Hamiltonian. Eigenvalues of H, do not have x dependence. Why?

Comment: Are you interested in *free particles* only? Or (also) bound particles?

Comment: @Gert No bound state problem in quantum mechanics, that I can remember, has $x$ dependent energy eigenvalue. I am asking why.

Comment: I solved analytically many bound state problems and do not recall a single solution with energy eigenvalues that are position-dependent. I doubt if there's some overarching principle explaining that. Instead it appears that the TISE always delivers position-independent Hamilt. eigenvalues. Looks like a property of the TISE to me. Not a very satisfying answer, I know...

Comment: Could it that it follows from $[\hat{x},\hat{H}]$ being nonzero?

Comment: Yes, you mentioned that but what makes you think non-commutation would lead to position independent $\hat{H}$ eigenvalues? I don't see the connection...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Hamiltonian of a particle in an external potential energy $V(x)$ can be written as
$$
H = -\frac{h^2}{2m} \nabla^2 + V(x)
$$
so indeed the energy operator does depend on the position coordinate.

It should be said, though, that a wave function $\psi(x)$ with definite energy $E$ satisfies
$$
H \psi(x) = E \psi(x)
$$
where $E$ is just a constant number. Eigenvalues, are, by definition, scalars. *However*, they depend on the parameters of the wave function. So for instance, if we have a collection of wave functions $\psi_i(x)$, where $i$ is just a label, then we can write
$$
H \psi_i(x) = E_i \psi_i(x).
$$
So here we see that the energy $E_i$, of course, depends on which wave function $\psi_i(x)$ we are talking about, i.e. it depends on the label $i$.

It's the exact same thing as having a matrix $A$ and a basis of eigenvectors $v_i$, which satisfy
$$
A v_i = \lambda_i v_i.
$$
The $\lambda_i$'s are constant, in the sense that they are scalars multiplying $v_i$, but obviously they depend on $i$!

If $V(x) = 0$, then we may label the wave functions $\psi_k(x)$ with the vector $k$ as
$$
\psi_k(x) = e^{- i k \cdot x}.
$$
So you see, $k$ is really a *label*, which labels different states $\psi_k(x)$. We then have
$$
H \psi_k(x) = \frac{\hbar^2 k^2}{2m} \psi_k(x)
$$
so
$$
E_k = \frac{\hbar^2 k^2}{2m}.
$$
Please notice that $E_k$ truly is a constant, because it just multiplies $\psi_k(x)$ as a scalar, but it depends on the *parameter* $k$, which labels which state you are talking about.

**Edit:** Proof: In order for $E$ to "depend" on the eigenvalue of the operator $\hat x$, the definite energy states would have to themselves be eigenstates of the $\hat x$ operator. These are given by the states
$$
\psi_{x_0}(x) = \delta(x_0 - x)
$$
where
$$
\hat x \psi_{x_0} (x) = x_0 \psi_{x_0}.
$$

If these states were eigenvectors of both $\hat x$ and $\hat H$, then $(\hat H \hat x - \hat x \hat H) \psi_{x_0}(x) = 0$. Because the $\psi_{x_0}(x)$ comprises a complete basis of states, then this proves that $[\hat{H},\hat{x}]=0$. Therefore $E$ cannot depend on the eigenvalues of $\hat x$ unless $[\hat{H},\hat{x}]=0$. QED.

Comment: But is it not worth asking why $x$ values do not appear as parameters in the energy eigenvalues? We can label the energy eigenfunctions in the free particle case by $k$ is that $[\hat p,\hat H]=0$ and $p=\hbar k$. In general, why $E_i=E(x_i)$ are forbidden?

Comment: This is only because in that case you are explicitly making a Hamiltonian which is built out of $p$ and not $x$, so the eigenvalues of $H$ will obviously be labelled by the eigenvalues of $p$. If you made the unphysical Hamiltonian $H = V(x)$, then the energy eigenstates would be $\psi_{x_0}(x) = \delta(x - x_0)$ with energy $E_{x_0} = V(x_0)$.

Comment: So are you saying that the x-independence of $E$ follows as a result of $[x,H]\neq 0$? In that case, one would like to see a proof.

Comment: You seem to be conflating a few different things. If $E$ depended on $x$, you would have the equation $H \psi(x) = E(x) \psi(x)$, which is nonsense! $E$ is a scalar (an eigenvalue) and isn't a function. However, it is also true that if you have two commuting Hermitian operators, $[A, B] = 0$, then you can simultaneously diagonalize both, meaning you can find a basis where $A v_i = \lambda^A_i v_i$ and $B v_i = \lambda^B_i v_i$. In this situation, $i$ labels both $\lambda^A_i$ and $\lambda^B_i$. This is the situation where you have $E = \hbar^2 k^2 / 2m$, where both $E$ and $p$ depend on $k$.

Comment: What stops an eigenvalue equation to be $H\psi_i(x)=E_i\psi_i(x)$ where $E_i=E(x_i,...)$ where $...$ may be other constants. Here, $x_i$ could be one partiuclar value of $x$, and hence a number or scalar or parameter, whatever you like.

Comment: That is indeed what happens in the case $H = V(x)$ I described above. Then $E(x_0) = V(x_0)$, where $x_0$ is the eigenvalue of the position operator.

Comment: But as you said, that's an unphysical problem where $[H,x]=0$. Also, that's the only case where you can come up with an example where $E$ depends parametrically on $x$. However, in general, $[H,x]\neq 0$. When $[H,x]\neq 0$, it is true that one cannot find simultaneous eigenfunctions of $H$ and $x$. Energy eigenfunctions cannot be labeled by $x$. But how does it preclude the energy eigenvalues to depend on $x$, parametrically?

Comment: Minor comment: "_but obviously they depend on $i$_". $i$ might be a set of indices, and in the case of degeneracy, the energy may not depend on all of them. For example, In nonrelativistic H atom for a given $n$, the energy of all the states $\psi_{nlm}$ depend on $n$ only.

Comment: Proof: In order for $E$ to "depend" on the eigenvalue of the operator $\hat x$, the definite energy states would have to themselves be eigenstates of the $\hat x$ operator. If that were the case, then $(\hat H \hat x - \hat x \hat H) \psi_{x_0}(x) = 0$. Because the $\psi_{x_0}(x)$ comprises a complete basis of states, then this proves that $[\hat H, \hat x] = 0$. Therefore $E$ cannot depend on the eigenvalues of $\hat x$ unless $[\hat H, \hat x] = 0$. QED.

Comment: Yes. That was my conjecture in the question. For the energy to depend on $x$, or be labelled by eigenvalues of $x$, $[H,x]=0$. The same is true for $p$. For the energy to depend on $p$, or be labelled by eigenvalues of $p$, $[H,p]=0$. So I wasn't conflating two different things :-)

Comment: @user1379857 Wait, it is obvious that for the position eigenvalues to be a label for the energy eigenvalues, the Hamiltonian would have to commute with the position operator. I think it ought to be explained/motivated as to why it would be disastrous for the Hamiltonian to commute with the position operator.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have an eigenstate of $H$, $\left|\psi\right\rangle $ of definite energy $E_0$. This means that the wave function in $E$-representation is,*
$$
\left\langle E\left|\psi\right.\right\rangle =\delta\left(E,E_{0}\right)
$$
Where by $\delta\left(E,E_{0}\right)$ I mean $\delta\left(E-E_{0}\right)$ if the spectrum is continuous, or $\delta_{E,E_{0}}$, in case it's discrete.
By twice using the closure relation --once in $x$-representation, and once in $E$-representation,
$$
I=\int dx\left|x\right\rangle \left\langle x\right|=\int dE\left|E\right\rangle \left\langle E\right|
$$
we get,
$$
\left|\psi\right\rangle =\int dx\left|x\right\rangle \left\langle x\left|\psi\right.\right\rangle =
$$
$$
=\int dx\int dE\left|x\right\rangle \left\langle x\left|E\right.\right\rangle \left\langle E\left|\psi\right.\right\rangle =
$$
$$
=\int dx\int dE\left|x\right\rangle \left\langle x\left|E\right.\right\rangle \delta\left(E,E_{0}\right)=
$$
$$
=\int dx\left|x\right\rangle \left\langle x\left|E_{0}\right.\right\rangle 
$$
What this identity is telling us is that when we have an eigenvector of the Hamiltonian with a definite value of $E$ (constant, yes, but constant with respect to what?), *all the possible values of* $x$ *are integrated into it* in some way, in the most general case in which $x$ and $H$ do not commute.

Now, suppose the Hamiltonian were *diagonal in the* $x$-*representation*. Which is what you seem to be suggesting as a possibility. Then, and only then --something that rarely ever happens--,
$$
\left\langle x\left|H\right|x'\right\rangle =E\left(x\right)\delta\left(x-x'\right)
$$
$$
E_{0}=\int dx\int dx'\left\langle E_{0}\left|x\right.\right\rangle E\left(x\right)\delta\left(x-x'\right)\left\langle x'\left|E_{0}\right.\right\rangle =
$$
$$
=\int dx\left\langle E_{0}\left|x\right.\right\rangle E\left(x\right)\left\langle x\left|E_{0}\right.\right\rangle =
$$
$$
=\int dxE\left(x\right)\left|\left\langle x\left|E_{0}\right.\right\rangle \right|^{2}
$$
There would be only one value of $x$ (say, $x_{0}$) that would give you a non-zero scalar product. And then,
$$
E_{0}=E\left(x_{0}\right)
$$
*I'm assuming that $\left\langle E\left|E\right.\right\rangle =1$, so I'm being somewhat cavalier there. I hope you forgive me.

Comment: I see @user1379857 has already included some of the points I'm making here. Sorry, it took me a while to edit, and some of the points weren't there when I started writing it. I will withdraw my answer if it happens to be repetitious.